# How can I send an appropriate HTTP status for MERGE statements?

Tags: java, web-services, oracle, rest, jax-rs

I am working on a RESTful API for one of our data models (Oracle) at work, and I am implementing it with JAX-RS (Java6 annotations).  The issue that I'm hoping to get some guidance on is how to return an appropriate HTTP Status method (201 for INSERT; 200 or 204 for UPDATE) upon successfully completing a PUT method, which is implemented using an idempotent MERGE query to the database.

Currently my Java logic looks similar to the following

```
int affectedRows = customDataBasePackage.executeUpdatePreparedStatement(insertSql, insertParams);
if( affectedRows < 1 ) {
  if( checkRowsSql == null || checkRowsParams == null ) {
    return Response.status(412).build();
  } else {
    return this.executeSELECTreturnJSON(checkRowsSql, checkRowsParams, 412, 409);
  }
} else {
  return Response.status(201).build();
}
```

The executeUpdatePreparedStatement(String,Object[]) method simply gets a PreparedStatement from the passed in sql, maps the parameters, and then executes PreparedStatement.executeUpdated();

Also, the reason I'm implementing my PUT method this way is because the the id column of this particular table is user generated, hence both INSERT and UPDATE methods must be idempotent. It's my understanding that the HTTP standard uses PUT for idempotent operations and POST for non-idempotent creation.

Thanks to taking the time to help!

Comment: merge can both insert and update rows in same statement (not just one or other), so maybe 200 for OK if no errors?

Comment: That's what I've been leaning towards, but it would be nice if there was some way to still use the MERGE statement while also keeping to the HTTP standard and sending the relevant 200,201 or 204 status back to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use code 301 Moved Permanently
For more information, you can check the following Link is REST Web services Book (page, 372) **301 (“Moved Permanently”)** :
http://www.crummy.com/writing/RESTful-Web-Services/RESTful_Web_Services.pdf
Also, you can check family search REST API response statuses codes over the following link: https://familysearch.org/developers/docs/guides/http-status-codes